# How do I convert xml to a Jenkins Job?

Tags: jenkins

I want to restore a deleted Jenkin's job. I had the JobConfig history plugin installed, but it does't have a restore option for that job. It only shows the xml file. I'm wondering how I can restore a Jenkin's job from that xml file.

[image: xml code]

Comment: This job seems pretty empty. However, this seems already be answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424228/export-import-jobs-in-jenkins

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be via the Jenkins REST API. I guess the recipe below would be dependent on the particular Jenkins version, so you may need to tweak it a bit. The version I looked at was 2.176.1

Go the Jenkins page for the folder in which you want the job created/restored.
On the page's footer you'll see a `REST API` link, go there.

On the `REST API` page you have all sorts of links, customized for your particular Jenkins server and job folder. You're looking for this section:

> Create Job
>
> To create a new job, post `config.xml` to [this URL](https://your_jenkins_server/your_job_folder_path/createItem) with query
>   parameter name=JOBNAME. You need to send a `Content-Type:
>   application/xml` header. You will get a `200` status code if the
>   creation is successful, or `4xx`/`5xx` code if it fails. `config.xml`
>   is the format Jenkins uses to store the project in the file system, so
>   you can see examples of them in the Jenkins home directory, or by
>   retrieving the XML configuration of existing jobs from
>   `/job/JOBNAME/config.xml`.